# Adding edge for open captions in Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, cc-2015

I'm on Mac OSX El Capitan, Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015 V10.3. I've created some open captions and I want to add some edge to them, to make them more readable. Only that I find no option for this. What should I do?

Screenshot:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that edged captions is a new feature in CC 2017, and is only available for open captions. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you found, and welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks : ) I'm a newbie and there's much for me to learn! Glad to have a supportive community on stackexchange.